# Mutation observer not being called when there's a change in Shadow Dom tree

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, mutation-observers

i have a running extension where i use combination of `mutation observer` and `tree walker` to filter out text nodes and embed React component on that page where i have text instances on the page. My problem is with the current state of functionality my extension doesn't work on website which have shadow dom in the page(doesn't filter out text nodes there). I did some investigation to see the problem, first i did some debugging  at tree walker level in filtering nodes after some more debugging it turns out my mutation observer is also not firing when there's a change in shadow tree.
i can't find much resources on this topic and i would like to know is it limitation of mutation observer to not detect changes inside nested shadow dom nodes?

Comment: Observe the shadow root of the node.

Comment: So i also need to make changes to my `treewalker` to handle `ShadowDom` nodes. I am only able to access `shadow` nodes in treewalker filter callback by using `node.shadowRoot`. This means that i have to separately  iterate on shadowDom tree in root document. Is this right approach doing like this?